C qsort fn segementation fault
I have the following comparison function:
  int compareByMemSize(const void *a, const void *b)
  {                                                                                                                                                                                           
      const struct ProcInfo *procInfo1 = (const struct ProcInfo *) a;
      const struct ProcInfo *procInfo2 = (const struct ProcInfo *) b;
   
      if (( procInfo1->memSize != NULL && procInfo1->memSize[0] != '\0' ) && ( procInfo2->memSize != NULL && procInfo2->memSize[0] != '\0' ))
      {
          long memSize1 = strtol(procInfo1->memSize, NULL, 10);
          long memSize2 = strtol(procInfo2->memSize, NULL, 10);
   
          if (memSize1 < memSize2)
              return -1;
          if (memSize1 > memSize2)
              return 1;
          return 0;
      }
   
      if (procInfo1->memSize == NULL && procInfo2->memSize == NULL)
          return 0;
      if (procInfo1->memSize == NULL)
          return -1;
      return 1;
  }

that does comparison logic for the following struct:
  typedef struct ProcInfo {                                                                                                                                                                   
      int  PID;
      char *name;
      char *memSize;
  } ProcInfo;

and I make the qsort call like so:
qsort(&a, sizeof(a), sizeof(ProcInfo), compareByMemSize);    

where a is of type of ProcArray:
typedef struct ProcArray {                                                                                                                                                                    
    ProcInfo *array;
    size_t used;
    size_t size;
} ProcArray;

the result is a seg fault and I think it's due to the fact that memSize could either be a long char arr, for example: 122313131 (it's a char[] because it originally contains a 'kB' and I took out the 'kB' for the comparison) or a '\0'.
Some memSize values originally also don't exist and so I compensated by setting their char[] to '\0', hence the check for that char above.
Am I just using qsort wrong? or is my approach to setting a char[] to '\0' if the value isn't found wrong?
If more code is needed, I'll be more than happy to provide!

Your sizeof(a) does not give you the number of array elements.

if more code is needed. Please post a Minimal Reproducible Example, the shortest complete code that shows the problem.

The call to qsort() is definitively wrong.  You might be able to use qsort(a.array, a.used, sizeof(ProcInfo), compareByMemSize);, but it might need to be different.  You're passing the address of a and telling qsort() that there are (probably) 24 elements in the array.  You might get away with passing the address of a since the address of a structure is also the address of the first element of the structure, albeit the two pointers are different types.  But sizeof(a) is going to be the size of the ProcArray structure in bytes, which is wholly unrelated to the size of the array.

And I see that Barmar's answer says much the same as my comment.  His answer wasn't visible when I started typing my comment.

P.S. instead of all those if statements, just subtract one item from the other.

a isn't an array of ProcInfo, it's a single ProcArray structure. The array that needs to be sorted is a.array.
qsort(a.array, a.used, sizeof(ProcInfo), compareByMemSize);

You don't need & when passing a.array because it's already a pointer.

amazing, can't believe I missed that. I'm getting output now for the first time but the numbers are semi-scrambled, a large segment sorted followed by unsorted segments, I'm thinking my comparison function isn't ideal, but thank you!

The first if statement checks for memSize being either a null pointer or pointing to an empty string. The later if statements only check for null pointers, not empty strings.

Why are you storing memSize as a string rather than parsing it to an integer when creating the structure?

initially when I read it in from the file, it contains a 'kB', so I store it as a char[]. should I set this prop to be an integer and do the string manipulation right off the rip? after reading it from the file?

Yes, that's what I'm suggesting.

That tip actually helped me so much, I ended up making two arrays, one for NULL values and one without. I was running into issues where some values that weren't NULL were still being placed into the array for non-NULL or '\0' values and somehow converting the char[] to int as soon as possible fixed this issue, memory is indeed complex..but fascinating

I  was thinking you could just default the length to 0 when it's null.

Let us continue this discussion in chat.
